# snprintf() in C giving off weird symbols into char array

Tags: c, printf, symbols

I am about to finish a project which consists on reading a .txt file and taking info from it to write it into another .txt. So far, I have managed to use read() to take in the information, but when I write into the new .txt something weird comes off:

```
    List of packages
----------------
- Package Name         : linux-api-headers
   - Install date      : 2019-03-22 21:24ÿÐüe2019-06-18 12:25
   - Last update date  : 2019-06-18 12:25
   - How many updates  : 2
   - Removal date      : -
- Package Name         : tzdata
   - Install date      : 2019-03-22 21:24ÿÐüe2019-09-17 12:39
   - Last update date  : 2019-09-17 12:39
   - How many updates  : 3
   - Removal date      : -
```

The input I read is like this:

```
[2019-03-22 21:21] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -r /mnt -Sy --cachedir=/mnt/var/cache/pacman/pkg --noconfirm base'
[2019-03-22 21:21] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] transaction started
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed linux-api-headers (4.17.11-1)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed tzdata (2018i-1)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed iana-etc (20190228-1)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed filesystem (2018.12-2)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed glibc (2.28-5)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed gcc-libs (8.2.1+20181127-1)
[2019-03-22 21:24] [ALPM] installed ncurses (6.1-6)
```

My program is meant to look for the keywords "installed", "upgraded", and "removed" and separate the date in which it happens and the name of the program and it looks like this (sorry if it appears messy):

```
void analyzeLog(char *logFile, char *report) {
      printf("Generating Report from: [%s] log file\n", logFile);

      char *file;
      int fd, i;
      int characters;
      char buffer[1], line[1024];
      int p;
      int upgraded, removed, installed;
      i = upgraded = removed = installed = 0;

      file = logFile;

      fd = open(file, O_RDONLY, 0600);

      //printf("%d\n\n\n\n", fd);

      if(fd == -1){
            //perror("open");
            printf("Unreadable");
            exit(1);
      }

      characters = read(fd, buffer, 1);

      for(;;)
      {
            characters = read(fd, buffer, 1);

            if(characters == -1){
                  printf("Error");
                  exit(1);
                  break;
            }
            else if(characters == 0) break;

            if(buffer[0] != '\n'){
                  line[i] = buffer[0];
                  i++;

            }
            else{
                  line[i++] = '\n';
                  line[i] = '\0';
                  i=0;
                  int j=0;
                  char *result;
                  //printf("problema\n");

                  if((result = strstr(line, "installed")) != NULL) {
                        //printf("instalacion\n");
                        char *doi, *position = strstr(result, " ")+1;
                        char nameOfProgram[64];
                        char dateOfInstall[20];

                        /*
                        printf("%c", position[0]);
                        printf("%c", position[1]);
                        printf("%c", position[2]);
                        printf("%c", position[3]);
                        printf("%c", position[4]);
                        */

                        while(position[j] != ' '){
                              nameOfProgram[j] = position[j];
                              j++;
                        }

                        nameOfProgram[j] = '\0';
                        j=0;

                        //printf("%s\n", nameOfProgram);

                        while(files[j].name[0] != '\0'){
                              if(strcmp(files[j].name, nameOfProgram) == 0) {
                                    j = -1;
                                    break;
                              }

                              j++;
                        }

                        if(j >= 0){
                              strcpy(files[j].name, nameOfProgram);
                              //printf("%s\n", files[j].name);
                              doi = strstr(line, "[")+1;
                              int k=0;

                              while(doi[k] != ']'){
                                    dateOfInstall[k] = doi[k];
                                    k++;
                              }

                              strcpy(files[j].installDate, dateOfInstall);

                        }

                        //printf("\n%s\n", position);

                        installed++;
                        //free(result);

                  }
                  else if((result = strstr(line, "removed")) != NULL) {
                        //printf("removido\n");
                        char *dor, *position = strstr(result, " ")+1;
                        char nameOfProgram[64];
                        char dateOfRemove[20];

                        while(position[j] != ' '){
                              nameOfProgram[j] = position[j];
                              j++;
                        }
                        nameOfProgram[j] = '\0';
                        j=0;
                        int comparison;

                        while(files[j].name[0] != '\0'){
                              if((comparison = strcmp(files[j].name, nameOfProgram)) == 0) {
                                    break;
                              }

                              j++;
                        }

                        if(comparison == 0){
                              dor = strstr(line, "[")+1;
                              int k=0;

                              while(dor[k] != ']'){
                                    dateOfRemove[k] = dor[k];
                                    k++;
                              }

                              strcpy(files[j].removeDate, dateOfRemove);
                        }

                        removed++;
                        //free(result);
                  }
                  else if((result = strstr(line, "upgraded")) != NULL) {
                        //printf("actualizado");
                        char *dou, *position = strstr(result, " ")+1;
                        char nameOfProgram[64];
                        char dateOfUpgrade[20];

                        while(position[j] != ' '){
                              nameOfProgram[j] = position[j];
                              j++;
                        }
                        nameOfProgram[j] = '\0';
                        j=0;
                        int comparison;

                        while(files[j].name[0] != '\0'){
                              if((comparison = strcmp(files[j].name, nameOfProgram)) == 0) {
                                    break;
                              }

                              j++;
                        }

                        if(comparison == 0){
                              dou = strstr(line, "[")+1;
                              int k=0;

                              while(dou[k] != ']'){
                                    dateOfUpgrade[k] = dou[k];
                                    k++;
                              }

                              strcpy(files[j].upgradeDate, dateOfUpgrade);

                              files[j].upgrades++;
                        }

                        upgraded++;

                  }

                  //printf("%s\n", line);
            }

      }

      //printf("\n\n%d, %d, %d \n\n", installed, removed, upgraded);

      if(close(fd) == -1){
            //perror("close");
            printf("Unreadable");
            exit(1);
      }
}
```

And this is my struct:

```
struct file{
      char name[64];
      char installDate[20];
      char upgradeDate[20];
      char removeDate[20];
      int upgrades;
};

struct file files[2048];
```

I already figure out that the problem comes when using the snprintf() function to pass the values into the char array right before doing the write:

```
if(files[j].name[0] != '\0'){

snprintf(input, max_size, 
"- Package Name         : %s\n"
"   - Install date      : %s\n"
"   - Last update date  : %s\n"
"   - How many updates  : %d\n"
"   - Removal date      : %s\n",
files[j].name, files[j].installDate, 
upD, files[j].upgrades, remD);

}
```

Every data in the "files" array is initialized with '\0' save for upgrades, since it is an int it is initialized at 0:

```
for(p=0; p<2048; p++){
      files[p].name[0] = '\0';
      files[p].installDate[0] = '\0';
      files[p].upgradeDate[0] = '\0';
      files[p].removeDate[0] = '\0';
      files[p].upgrades = 0;
}
```

Does anybody know why it could be giving off those strange characters and the repeated date in the "Install date" part?

Comment: Hard to determine from this amount of information. Maybe installDate is not null terminated?

Comment: In MSVC there is a difference in behaviour between `snprintf` and `_snprintf`. The first is guaranteed to null-terminate, the second is not.

Comment: Maybe you have garbage in `files[j].installDate` at some point. Maybe `input` is not large enough or `max_size` is wrong, who knows. With your debugger that shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: We need more context to help you. How do you initalize the variables, what is the input you read, which output do you expect, etc...

Comment: Are you using `read` or `fread`?  If not using `fgets`, there's a very good chance that your arrays are not null-terminated.  You'll need to show the code in which you read the data.

Comment: It sounds like an undefined memory reference somewhere.  If the program is small, just try looking for strings that are malsized or used-before-set.  Or try valgrind or gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2, and crank up your compiler's warning level.  For general background: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/checking-early.html

Comment: Looks like snprintf is fine, and you have a problem with files[j].installDate

Comment: I already updated the question with more information, I was trying to keep it simple but I already put most of what is needed to understand it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was not putting the null terminator when creating the installDate, removeDate, etc. It is solved.